# Unusual program?! RLT5S or RLTS5, Icon Implies Internet

Tags: windows-10

I found this program when I restarted for a Win10 update - it was having trouble shutting down, and had an icon that looked like an ethernet cable hooking up to a globe.  Anyone have any idea what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably [RtlS5Wake.exe](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/rtls5wake-app-trojan-virus/0679ba15-961e-45f3-8b53-f25f5fedcbed), which according to multiple sources is a tool for a Realtek Wireless LAN card known as the Realtek WOWL Utility.

Per that thread it may mean that you need to find out what network card you have and update the driver from the manufacturer's website. Or you can just disable the tool as described in that link.

If you know for a fact that you do not have a Realtek network card then you may have a malware infection, but as someone else has the same problem it is unlikely.